# String Replace in TeamCity for windows

Tags: teamcity

I'm trying to replace the slash character / with an underscore _ using the following lines in a script in TeamCity on windows:

```
set destination_dir=%teamcity.build.branch%
set destination_dir=%%destination_dir:/=_%%
```

With the code as I have it, run through TeamCity it echoes as

```
set destination_dir=/=_
```

which leads to the string being simply "/"

I feel confident in my approach because when I replace %teamcity.build.branch% with a string, and use single % instead of %% this does exactly what I want in a command prompt.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which VCS is this? 
Are you passing the variable %teamcity.build.branch% as a param to your script?

Comment: Its a custom script defined in build step. %teamcity.build.branch% has a value such as gaf/mybranch

Answer (score 0):

Okay - so you need to pass the variable as a parameter to your custom script.

```
set destination_dir=%1
set destination_dir=%%destination_dir:/=_%%
```

And in teamcity step call your custom script like

```
yourcustomscript.bat %teamcity.build.branch%
```